# On Linux or Windows, how do I find the path for all mp3s that are the only mp3 in that directory?

Tags: linux, windows, script, find, mp3

I have a Music folder and the contents look like this:

```
Music
    -ArtistA
        -Song1.mp3
        -AlbumA
            -Song2.mp3
            -Song2.m4a
        -AlbumB
            -Song1.mp3
            -Song2.mp3
            -Song3.mp3
        -AlbumC
            -Song1.mp3
            -Song1.jpg
            -SomeFolder1
                -Song1.mp3
    -ArtistB
        -Song1.mp3
    -ArtistC
        -Song1.mp3
        -Song2.mp3
        -Song3.mp3
        -SomeFolder2
            -Song1.jpg
            -Song2.jpg
        -SomeFolder3
```

I am looking for output like this:

```
ArtistA/Song1.mp3
ArtistA/AlbumA/Song2.mp3
ArtistA/AlbumC/Song1.mp3
ArtistA/AlbumC/SomeFolder1/Song1.mp3
ArtistB/Song1.mp3
```

So, I don't want directories with only one file, I want directories with only one mp3 - regardless of subdirectories or other files.  I also do not want empty directories, or directories which contain more than one mp3.
I am not opposed to a shell script for Linux.  I don't want to compile a program on either OS, however.

I have tried:
`find . -type d -exec sh -c 'set -- "$0"/*.mp3; [ $# -le 1 ]' {} \; -print`
but that gives me this output:

```
.
./ArtistB
./ArtistA
./ArtistA/AlbumA
./ArtistA/AlbumC
./ArtistA/AlbumC/SomeFolder1
./ArtistC/SomeFolder2
./ArtistC/SomeFolder3
```

which is close, but not exactly what I want.  There are two empty folders and no filenames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first glance, the reason why your first command is reporting the empty folders
(those with no `*.mp3` files) is that you’re saying `-le 1` rather than `-eq 1`. 
This looks like it will report directories with one MP3 file or fewer. 
But changing `-le 1` to `-eq 1` doesn’t work. 
It turns out that the problem is, in a directory with ≥ one MP3 file,
`directory_name/*.mp3` gets you a list of the MP3 file names,
but, in a directory with none, it remains, literally, as `directory_name/*.mp3`. 
That can be fixed by telling the shell
that wildcards that match no files should simply vanish from the command line:

```
find . -type d -exec
        sh -c 'shopt -s nullglob; set -- "$0"/*.mp3; [ $# -eq 1 ]' {} \; -print
```

(typed all as one line) yields

```
./ArtistA
./ArtistA/AlbumA
./ArtistA/AlbumC
./ArtistA/AlbumC/SomeFolder1
./ArtistB
```

But you’ve got the shell counting the files, and you’re asking `find` to do the printing
– and `find` is looking only at directories. 
Why not just let the shell print the filename that it sees?

```
find . -type d -exec
        sh -c 'shopt -s nullglob; set -- "$0"/*.mp3; [ $# -eq 1 ] && echo "$1"' {} \;
```

(i.e., if there is one file, `echo` the name of the first one (`$1`)) will give you what you want.

Answer (score 5):

For Windows using PowerShell, assuming you're already in the folder C:\YOUR_PATH:

```
PS C:\YOUR_PATH> (Get-ChildItem -recurse | Where-Object {$_.name -match ".mp3"}) | Group-Object -Property Directory | Where-Object {$_.Count -eq 1} | ForEach-Object { (Get-ChildItem $_.Name -Filter "*.mp3").FullName}
```

Outputs:

```
C:\YOUR_PATH\ArtistA\Song1.mp3
C:\YOUR_PATH\ArtistA\AlbumA\Song2.mp3
C:\YOUR_PATH\ArtistA\AlbumC\Song1.mp3
C:\YOUR_PATH\ArtistA\AlbumC\SomeFolder1/Song1.mp3
C:\YOUR_PATH\ArtistB\Song1.mp3
```

**Breaking down the piped command:**

Get all files and folder underneath current directory

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse
```

Match only the files based on your mask

```
Where-Object {$_.name -match ".mp3"})
```

Perform grouping based on Directory property

```
Group-Object -Property Directory
```

Select only the directories with 1 item

```
Where-Object {$_.Count -eq 1}
```

Extract the full name of the one file matching your filemask in each directory

```
ForEach-Object { (Get-ChildItem $_.Name -Filter "*.mp3").FullName}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure someone has a better way of doing it, but this bash command will work on Linux.

```
for Folder in $(find . -name "*.mp3" -printf "%h\n")
do
    [[ $(ls -l $Folder/*.mp3 | wc -l) -eq "1" ]] && ls $Folder/*.mp3
done
```

This script performs a test on the folder of every single .mp3 file, repeating itself for each match on the same file. For instance, it checks Music/ArtistA/AlbumB 3 times. Depending on how many mp3 files you have, this could take a long time (you'd need a pretty huge library).

If so, you can make it slightly more complicated:

```
for Folder in $(find . -name "*.mp3" -printf "%h\n" | awk '!x[$0]++')
    do
        [[ $(ls -l $Folder/*.mp3 | wc -l) -eq "1" ]] && ls $Folder/*.mp3
    done
```

The result is the same, but it'll only check each folder once, which could save a lot of time. The awk command removes any duplicate Folder names.

Another note is that files are case sensitive on Linux, so this will totally ignore any `.MP3` or `.Mp3`files. If you want it to match those, change all 3 instances of `mp3` to `[mM][pP]3`

Comment: protip: to make find use case insensitive matches for filenames, you can use -iname <pattern> instead of -name <pattern>.

Comment: True, but it needs the regex in the ls commands anyway, so I thought I'd keep it consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer:

```
find Music -name "*.mp3" -exec dirname {} \; |
    sort |
    uniq -c |
        while read count parent
        do
            if [[ $count -eq 1 ]]
            then
                echo "$parent"/*.mp3
            fi
        done
```

Comment: Try replacing the inner `find` with `echo "$parent"/*.mp3`.